# How to write oracle insert script with one field as CLOB?

Tags: oracle

I want to create an insert script which will be used only to insert one record into one table.

It has 5 columns and one of them is of type CLOB.

Whenever I try, it says can not insert string is so long . larger than 4000.

I need an insert statement with clob as one field.

```
INSERT INTO tbltablename 
            (id, 
             NAME, 
             description, 
             accountnumber, 
             fathername) 
VALUES      (1, 
             N'Name', 
             clob'some very long string here, greater than 4000 characters', 
             23, 
             'John') ;
```

Answer (score 24):

Keep in mind that SQL strings can not be larger than 4000 bytes, while Pl/SQL can have strings as large as 32767 bytes.  see below for an example of inserting a large string via an anonymous block which I believe will do everything you need it to do.

**note I changed the varchar2(32000) to CLOB**

```
set serveroutput ON 
CREATE TABLE testclob 
  ( 
     id NUMBER, 
     c  CLOB, 
     d  VARCHAR2(4000) 
  ); 

DECLARE 
    reallybigtextstring CLOB := '123'; 
    i                   INT; 
BEGIN 
    WHILE Length(reallybigtextstring) <= 60000 LOOP 
        reallybigtextstring := reallybigtextstring 
                               || '000000000000000000000000000000000'; 
    END LOOP; 

    INSERT INTO testclob 
                (id, 
                 c, 
                 d) 
    VALUES     (0, 
                reallybigtextstring, 
                'done'); 

    dbms_output.Put_line('I have finished inputting your clob: ' 
                         || Length(reallybigtextstring)); 
END; 

/ 
SELECT * 
FROM   testclob; 


 "I have finished inputting your clob: 60030"
```

Comment: That's a good answer for CLOBs up to 32'000 characters. For bigger CLOBs, you need to create a temporary CLOB (see DBMS_LOB package), append data to it in chunks of 32'000 and the insert that temporary CLOB into the table.

Comment: @codo, that is a really good point, but in this example dbms_lob was unnecessary - at least in 11r1 (and I should not have set the ReallyBigTextString as a VARCHAR2(32000) -- I will amend the above example.

Comment: You're partially right. The use of DBMS_LOB is probabably not needed. But if you're not using an artificial string - as you do by repeating the same substring again and again - then you're limited by the size of the declare/begin/end block. At a certain size (about 100K), you get an error message. So you have to split your long string into chunks and split it over several declare/begin/end blocks. At that's rather tricky.

Comment: Also keep in mind that SQL*Plus only supports 2499 characters on a line.

Comment: @Codo, in Oracle 10g a feature called "SQL semantics for LOB" was introduced. Thus for certain operations like concatenation package `DBMS_LOB` is not required anymore.

Answer (score 8):

I solved my problem with a solution that is *simpler* than the most voted answer.

You must divide your big clob string into multiple strings, each one with less than 4000 chars, convert each one using the `to_clob` method, and concatenate them with the `||` operator.

Here is an example of the final insert statement:

```sql
INSERT INTO tbltablename 
            (id, 
             name, 
             big_clob_description) 
VALUES      (1, 
             N'A Name', 
             to_clob('string with less than 4000 chars') 
             || to_clob('rest of string here, with less than 4000 chars') 
) ;
```

My insert code was generated by a script, and it wasn't difficult to break the strings.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `to_clob` function too.

```
INSERT INTO tbltablename 
            (id, 
             NAME, 
             description, 
             accountnumber, 
             fathername) 
VALUES      (1, 
             N'Name', 
             to_clob('clob''some very long string here, greater than 4000 characters'), 
             23, 
             'John') ;
```

You can find more information here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions182.htm.

Regards.