# How can I insert into a BLOB column from an insert statement in sqldeveloper?

Tags: oracle, blob, oracle-sqldeveloper

Is it possible to insert into a `BLOB` column in oracle using sqldeveloper?

i.e. something like:

```
insert into mytable(id, myblob) values (1,'some magic here');
```

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, e.g. using the implicit conversion from RAW to BLOB:

```
insert into blob_fun values(1, hextoraw('453d7a34'));
```

`453d7a34` is a string of hexadecimal values, which is first explicitly converted to the RAW data type and then inserted into the BLOB column. The result is a BLOB value of 4 bytes.

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work if the BLOB is greater than 2000 bytes - because there is a limitation in Oracle that a char constant can't be greater than 4000 characters.

Answer (score 60):

To insert a `VARCHAR2` into a `BLOB` column you can rely on the function `utl_raw.cast_to_raw` as next:

```
insert into mytable(id, myblob) values (1, utl_raw.cast_to_raw('some magic here'));
```

It will cast your input `VARCHAR2` into `RAW` datatype without modifying its content, then it will insert the result into your `BLOB` column.

More details about the function [`utl_raw.cast_to_raw`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/appdev.920/a96612/u_raw2.htm#1003683)

Comment: `UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW` has a limit of 2000 chars. How to insert a value > 2000 chars ? (used on Oracle)

Comment: You can use too the `to_clob` function.  check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68808988/1610853

Answer (score 1):

Using SQL DEVELOPER
you can add the record with an insert like this

Insert into MY_TABLE (KEYSTRING,BLOB) values (123, '');

After that you can save blob content (a big string>4000 char for example) into a file.txt

upload it from SQL DEVELOPER

- opening TABLE edit tool (you can open it by searching table from "Find Database Object" tool)
- go in "Data" tab
- search record 123
- edit BLOB column value by pencil icon

[image]

- Load Local data and upload file.txt
  [image]

Answer (score -1):

1. insert into mytable(id, myblob) values (1,EMPTY_BLOB);
2. SELECT * FROM mytable mt where mt.id=1 for update
3. Click on the Lock icon to unlock for editing
4. Click on the ... next to the BLOB to edit
5. Select the appropriate tab and click open on the top left.
6. Click OK and commit the changes.

Comment: This case not working.