# multiple BLOB file insertion in oracle using SQLdeveloper

Tags: sql, oracle, blob, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to insert Multiple BLOB file at once ​​in "USER_PROFILE" table using loop by procedure/function.
Working on Oracle DB using SQLdeveloper

- BLOB Files:

  1. user.resetpassword.email.body.html
  2. password.expiry.notification.email.html
  3. password.expiry.notification.subject.txt
  4. user.resetpassword.email.subject.txt
- BLOB FILE DIRECTORY : U_PROFILE
- BLOB column name : PROP_VALUE
- Unique key : PROP_KEY (This column naming conventions will be same with BLOB file names)

  CREATE TABLE "USER_PROFILE" (
      "USER_PROFILE_PID"  VARCHAR2(40 BYTE)
      , "PROP_KEY"          VARCHAR2(100 BYTE)
      , "PROP_VALUE"        BLOB
      , "MODIFIED_DTS"      DATE
      , "BUILD_VERSION"     VARCHAR2(100 BYTE)
      , "DESCRIPTION"       VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE)
  )

  ​;

  INSERT INTO user_profile (
      user_profile_pid
      , prop_key
      , modified_dts
      , build_version
      , description
  ) VALUES (
      'CTP-1000'
    , 'password.expiry.notification.email'
    , NULL
    , '1.2'
    , 'User Account Expiry notification'
  );

  INSERT INTO user_profile (
      user_profile_pid
      , prop_key
      , modified_dts
      , build_version
      , description
  ) VALUES (
      'CTP-1001'
    , 'password.expiry.notification.subject'
    , NULL
    , '1.2'
    , 'User Account Expiry notification subject'
  );

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7489359/how-can-i-insert-into-a-blob-column-from-an-insert-statement-in-sqldeveloper - otherwise you will want to look at something like sqlldr to batch load blobs to a table

Comment: Shared answer is a different prospect. I want to insert multiple files at one using loop.

Comment: yet my suggestion stands...there's no, 'insert' statement that will take a file on the client and insert it as a blob on the database

Comment: I have heard about use program "DBMS_LOB.loadfromfile" .

Comment: yes, and here's an example - https://oracle-base.com/articles/8i/import-blob - note that the blob files will need to already be on the server

Comment: I am able to insert with query, but I need to insert multiple files using file name.Can you help me for that,

Comment: shanny - add a column to track file names and update as needed, that's the most reliable way of handling files in the db