# How to Upload BLOB Data Type to a TABLE in SQL Developer?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

How can I upload **BLOB DATA TYPE** to a TABLE in **SQL Developer**? I have created a TABLE with blob data types but when I try to upload data to the table it's show this error:

`ORA-00936: missing expression`

This is the script that I'm using to upload data to the table

```
INSERT INTO IMAGEN (
                    ID_ADM,
                    ID_USUARIO,
                    IMAGEN,
                    MINIATURA,
                    IMAGEN_ALT1,
                    IMAGEN_ALT2,
                    IMAGEN_ALT3,
                    ESTADO_REG,
                    FEC_ESTADO_REG,
                    FEC_ING_REG,
                    ID_USUARIO_ING_REG,
                    FEC_ULT_MODIF_REG,
                    ID_USUARIO_ULT_MODIF_REG,
                    ID_FUNCION_ULT_MODIF_REG)
                VALUES (
                    :VID_ADM,
                    :VID_USUARIO,
                    :VIMAGEN,
                    :VMINIATURA,
                    :VIMAGEN_ALT1,
                    :VIMAGEN_ALT2,
                    :VIMAGEN_ALT3,
                    'V',
                    DATE(3),
                    DATE(3),
                    :VUSU,
                    DATE(3),
                    :VUSU,
```

And this is the code that I used to create the table.

```
create table IMAGEN (
       ID_ADM                    smallint not null
       , ID_USUARIO                varchar2(20) not null
       , IMAGEN                    blob
       , MINIATURA                 blob
       , IMAGEN_ALT1               blob
       , IMAGEN_ALT2               blob
       , IMAGEN_ALT3               blob
       , ESTADO_REG                varchar2(1) null
       , FEC_ESTADO_REG            date null
       , FEC_ING_REG               date null
       , ID_USUARIO_ING_REG        varchar2(20) null
       , FEC_ULT_MODIF_REG         date null
       , ID_USUARIO_ULT_MODIF_REG  varchar2(20) null
       , ID_FUNCION_ULT_MODIF_REG  varchar2(16) null
);
```

Comment: You need to post your query that's getting the error.

Comment: Ok, sorry I have just uploaded it. Thanks for read this !

Comment: [SQL Developer](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/sqldeveloper-landing.html) or [PL/SQL Developer](https://www.allroundautomations.com/products/pl-sql-developer/)?

Comment: You only have 13 values for 14 columns in the `INSERT` query. And how are you providing the values for the placeholders?

Comment: It is SQLDeveloper , excuse me !!

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7489359/how-can-i-insert-into-a-blob-column-from-an-insert-statement-in-sqldeveloper

Comment: What is `DATE(3)`?

Comment: `DATE(3)` It is dates of modification of the table , when the user insert an image to the table , this must show the date when the image was inserted

Comment: No answers in the question, please. I have rolled back/edited your question and removed the answer. Add the answer in the answer section only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By this way finally works on my code !

```
INSERT INTO USU_USUARIOS_IMAGEN (
        ID_ADM,
        ID_USUARIO,
        IMAGEN,
        MINIATURA,
        IMAGEN_ALT1,
        IMAGEN_ALT2,
        IMAGEN_ALT3,
        ESTADO_REG,
        FEC_ESTADO_REG,
        FEC_ING_REG,
        ID_USUARIO_ING_REG,
        FEC_ULT_MODIF_REG,
        ID_USUARIO_ULT_MODIF_REG,
        ID_FUNCION_ULT_MODIF_REG)
 VALUES (
        VID_ADM,
        VID_USUARIO,
        VIMAGEN,
        VMINIATURA,
        VIMAGEN_ALT1,
        VIMAGEN_ALT2,
        VIMAGEN_ALT3,
        'V',
        sysdate,
        sysdate,
        VUSU,
        sysdate,
        VUSU,
        VFUN);
```