# I wanted to insert a file type into a table but unable to do that in Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am learning SQL, and created an entity using the following query in Oracle SQL Developer.

```
CREATE TABLE application (
    applicationid      NUMBER,
    proofofidentity    BLOB NOT NULL,
    status             VARCHAR2(50) DEFAULT 'PENDING',
    userid       NUMBER NOT NULL,
    adminid     NUMBER NOT NULL
);
```

Now I want to insert few rows. So, I wanted to know how can I directly get the file, convert it into BLOB and insert it?

I tried the below mentioned query but it didn't work :/

```
DECLARE
    l_bfile BFILE;
    l_blob  BLOB;
BEGIN

    l_bfile := BFILENAME('C:/Users/user name/Desktop/practice', 'proofofidentity_sample.pdf');
    DBMS_LOB.fileopen(l_bfile, DBMS_LOB.file_readonly);

    -- Initialize the BLOB
    DBMS_LOB.createtemporary(l_blob, TRUE);

    -- Load the file into the BLOB
    DBMS_LOB.loadfromfile(l_blob, l_bfile, DBMS_LOB.getlength(l_bfile));
    
    BEGIN 
        INSERT INTO application (applicationid, proofofidentity, status, userid, adminid)
        VALUES (1, l_blob, 'Approved', 1, 1);
    EXCEPTION
     WHEN OTHERS THEN 
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Error in the INSERT: ' || SQLERRM);

END;
/
```

I got the below error, tried for multiple paths, and unfortunately they didn't work.

```
Error report -
ORA-22285: non-existent directory or file for FILEOPEN operation
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_LOB", line 822
ORA-06512: at line 7
22285. 00000 -  "non-existent directory or file for %s operation"
*Cause:    Attempted to access a directory that does not exist, or attempted
           to access a file in a directory that does not exist.
*Action:   Ensure that a system object corresponding to the specified
           directory exists in the database dictionary, or
           make sure the name is correct.
```

Comment: `fileopen` is used to open files on the server, not on the client system. A plsql script can't open files on the client system.

Comment: Have a look at this answer, it is quite complete: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7489359/how-can-i-insert-into-a-blob-column-from-an-insert-statement-in-sqldeveloper