# What is the Oracle NCLOB datatype max character length?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, nclob

I added `NCLOB` column to table:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD(column_name NCLOB);
```

And I tried insert large text to this column which length is equal 22000. 
But I get "*Too long value*" error.
What is the maximum length of `NCLOB`? (I use Oracle 11g)

Comment: The maximum length is 4 GB of data, which comes down to 2 GB of characters. Obviously that's not your problem. How are you inserting the data? Through a query or a UI?

Comment: from UI, I insert only string, and it's length is 22000. What is a best way for it?

Comment: Try just using a plain query. The UI may have its own restrictions on what it can support. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3890567/how-to-write-oracle-insert-script-with-one-field-as-clob (and related questions).

Comment: But from what UI? SQL*Plus? SQL Developer? DBeaver? A custom program?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález, I added column from Navicat and insert to data from web application

Comment: Could we know the language the web application is written with and see the relevant insertion code?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález, I used `ASP.NET MVC5 ` and insert code is pure `SQL` insert query.

Comment: So you use whatever database class the framework provides as default? Do you inject the value into the query or use prepared statements? (Whatever, I know nothing about ASP.NET, sorry.)

Comment: The maximum length of a character _literal_ (constant) is 4000 byte (**not** characters). So if you supply  a character literal that is longer then that, you will also get that error. You have to use bind variables if you want to insert longer values (actually you should **always** use bind variables if only for security reasons)